# Abstract Class needs to know all Extending Classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns

So I have a class, AbtractParent, and an arbitrary amount of subclasses which extend it.

Each subclass has a string associated with it.

Eventually, I want to be able to write code along the lines of

```
if(AbstractParent.doesStringRepresentSubClass("example String"))
   AbstractParent.getInstOfSubClassReppedBy("example String");
```

My current solution is to store a map as a static variable of AbstractParent and have each subclass add an instance of itself and its string to this map.

The problem is that by doing this, AbstractParent now has knowledge of every one of its subclasses, which seems contrary to the ideas of OOP.

My only other solution ideas are

1. have a config file where every sub class writes its class name and string representation
2. every time i create a subclass, add a line of code to an if-else statement inside of the doesStringRepresentSubClass .

Is their a better, more OOP proper design way of doing this?

Thanks all!

Edit 1: The string representation WILL NOT be the same as the class name and thus cannot be cast to a Type using reflection.

Edit 2: The end goal here is to follow the Open Close principle and thus the creation of a subclass should require editing only the subclass file. Due to this a factory method can't be used to solve the problem entirely.

That said, separating my above code into both a factory class and an abstract parent class is definitely good design that I will implement.

Comment: Take a look at the Factory-Pattern: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method

Comment: "*the creation of a subclass should require editing only the subclass file*" - This is sort of impossible. You create a new class, write therein a magic String and expect to find it. You can do it using classpath scanning, but this works only locally (i.e. not with classes loaded via internet, etc.).

Comment: @maaartinus Thanks! That's kind of what I was scared of. Looks like I'm stuck with my initial map solution or Reflection.

Answer (score 5):

This looks to me like you're trying to implement a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Your factory method would have a knowledge of each subclass and how to instantiate it given a string. Note that this knowledge doesn't reside in the base class of the objects you're creating.

e.g.

```
public class Factory {
   public AbstractParent newInstance(String spec) {
      if ("example String".equals(spec)) {
         return new ExampleStringSubclass();
      }
      // etc.
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, I had a feeling I was going for some kind of factory. Unfortunately, judging by the example in the link you sent, I'm still not quite seeing how to do it? Would yo mind expounding a little?

Comment: Thanks Brian. Using this method, it seems that every time I created a new subclass I would need to add an else if to to my newInstance method, is that right?

Comment: That's correct. The string specifies how to build a suitable instance. You could (for example) use a combination of parameters to control this.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that won't work for me Brian. This requires new classes to edit a second file and thus doesn't follow the Open-Close principle. See my edit for more details on what I'm going for.

Thanks though!

Comment: I think that's going to be extraordinarily difficult. The factory buys you some isolation since it's only building the classes to be used, so a new subtype should be relatively safe

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be easily solved using reflection. [These](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) methods will be useful. First you instantiate class for name and then check if this is a subclass of your AbstractParent.

Comment: It is not recommended to use reflection when there are safer and cleaner ways to resolve a problem (see the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a proper way to use inheritance in this case.

Because base class doesn't need to know its subclasses, otherwise, your design forces `AbstractParent` to be modified each time when extended. In addition, `AbstractParent` cannot be substituted with subclasses, it's **Liskov Substitution** Principle.

It also violates **Single Responsibility** Principle, `AbstractParent` works as both Parent and factory.

And a minor problem: using Enum as key is better than `String`.

Comment: The violation of Open-Close is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. By using the map approach I described, Open-Close is preserved but the relationship between parent and sub class is cyclical and thus wong. Any idea how to do this while preserving open-close?

Answer (score 1):

```
AbstractParent getInstOfSubClassReppedBy(string name) 
{

Type t = Type.GetType(name);
return (AbstractParent) Activator.CreateInstance(t);

}

bool doesStringRepresentSubClass(string name)
{

return Type.GetType(name).IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractParent))

}
```

And then you can add some error checking

Comment: The only problem with this is it requires the Streng Representation of the class to match directly with the class name.

Given how I'll be using this that isn't a feasible approach. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
Ok, I understand better what you want, try this. (It's C# but im sure you can translate it) into java

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Parent> _dic;

    static Parent()
    {
        var subTypes =
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type =>
            !type.IsAbstract
            && !type.IsInterface
            && type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]) != null  //Has empty constructor
            && typeof(Parent).IsAssignableFrom(type));

        foreach (var type in subTypes)
        {
            Parent obj = (Parent)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            _dic.Add(obj.Identifier,  obj);
        }
    }

    public static bool IsSubClass(string s)
    {
        return _dic.ContainsKey(s);
    }

    public static Parent GetInstance(string s)
    {
        return _dic[s];
    }

    protected abstract string Identifier { get;}
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    protected override string Identifier
    {
        get { return "MyIdentifier"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, this looks like C# to me, not Java. Second, since your CreateInstance method isn't static, you can only use it if you already have an instance already, so what's the point?

Comment: This looks like it would require Java Reflections, definitely a valid approach. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually such things doesn't belong to the abstract class. Instead, they are put in a separate class that is called a factory class. Often it's abstract too and can have different implementations, but that's not strictly necessary. The difference is that your abstract parent class now doesn't know anything about its subclasses, but the factory class does. How you implement the factory class is up to you. You can't use switch/case for strings in Java, though. I usually implement this kind of thing as a long chain of "if"s. A map could be used too, but you should put Class objects or class names in it, not instances. Only create instances when getInstOfSubClassReppedBy() is called.

P. S. However, I did use the "abstract parent is also a factory" approach in practice. It makes sense when the set of subclasses is fixed and they are all belong to the same project, and it wouldn't make any sense to define subclasses anywhere else. For example, I have an implementation of some protocol involving a fixed set of commands and answers that are sent in XML. When I get an XML answer I call the XMLAnswer.fromXML(xml) method which belongs to the abstract parent. It figures out from the XML which subclass to create. Now, since the set of answers is defined by the protocol, I can only add a subclass when a new protocol version is released, so the whole thing needs to be changed. I could use a factory class too, but that wouldn't serve any particular purpose as the whole thing is package-private anyway, and there is no mechanism for extending the protocol on-the-fly. So the base class could be used as a factory sometimes, but this technique should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

Although, for all reasons given in other answers, I would not recommend you to write your code in your `AbstractParent`, but in some Factory class, you could take a look at [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library, which provide easy to use introspection utils.